# HTML Radio checkbox weird behavior - Unable to check

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to "select a size" on a product [page](https://www.footlocker.ca/en/product/jordan-retro-1-high-og-mens/4104250.html?pickupStore=&style=0&size=09.0) via javascript. When a size is selected, the corresponding size's `div` tag class attribute is appended with `c-form-field--checked`.

I have  used javascript to manually alter the class name to the specifications above. However, when I submit the "Add to Cart" button, it says that I have not selected a size.

I have also observed that the "checked" property for the radio input is not updated unless I select another HTML tag and come back to it later in chrome dev tools (accessibility tab). The property in question also doesn't update when i call the `check` method on it.

Not sure what I'm missing here, as HTML differ only also spots the change in the class name when selecting a size.

Comment: `I have used javascript to manually alter the class name to the specifications above. However, when I submit the "Add to Cart" button, it says that I have not selected a size` - just click the thing then - why are you messing with classes? that's just a visual indicator, a LOT more goes on when you click a size than adding a class to a div!!!

Comment: try calling the `click` method on the *radio* `input` instead of messing with a visual style of a `div`

Comment: I've tried the click method. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything (the red highlight doesn't appear when I call that method )

Comment: you're doing it wrong ... works perfectly **from the console** - how are you doing it?

Comment: I did `document.querySelector('div[class="c-form-field c-form-field--radio ProductSize"]').querySelector('input').click` in the console (this selects the first instock size and clicks it). But not sure what I'm doing wrong. The class name now has "error" in it when i try to add to cart, as nothing has been selected.

Comment: try `documen...ut').click()` to **call** the function

Comment: Thank you! Can't believed I missed it.